# Solving recursions with combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, recursion

*A child is running up a staircase with n steps and can hop either 1 step, 2 steps, or 3 steps at a time. Count how many possible ways the child can run up the stairs.*

This is a problem on Cracking the Code Inteview but I'm wondering if there's a way to solve this with combinatorics; essentially directly calculate the answer without dynamic programming.

Comment: You may need to solve $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly solve the recurrence explicitly.  If $A(n)$ is the ordered number of ways to sum to $n$ using $1,2,3$ we have $A(n)=A(n-1)+A(n-2)+A(n-3)$, the [Tribonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers) numbers but offset by $2$ because in your case $A(0)=A(1)=1$.  They are given in [OEIS A000073](https://oeis.org/A000073).  There are various forms of a closed form solution given.  The usual approach to homogeneous recurrence relations applies, assume a solution of the form $r^n$.  Plugging that in gives $r^3=r^2+r+1$, which has three roots $r_1,r_2,r_3$.  The general solution is $ar_1^n+br_2^n+cr_3^n$.  You find $a,b,c$ from the initial conditions.